# SSH service fails to start

Tags: server, ssh, openssh

I just created a virtual machine based on cloud images (of Lunar Lobster) on VMWare. Unfortunately it fails to start ssh. If I try to enable or restart the service I get:

[image]

And if I check journal it is empty (not containing anything regarding ssh). If I check on status it responds:

[image]

Unfortunately no details are provided. How do I search for the reason or fix that error?

Comment: Could you provide the full output of `sudo systemctl status ssh.service`? It also has some log information. And please as text in your post, and not images. Thanks.

Comment: Totally, agreed, VMWare console does not let me copy text, so apologies for pictures here. The log below only says "ssh.service: Start request repeated too quickly" and then "Failed with result 'exit-code'."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Rachel's answer about how to test for errors and how to debug, I was able to fix that by regenerating host keys.

The solution was

```
/usr/bin/ssh-keygen -A
```

After a service restart ssh operates as expected.

Comment: Please upvote the useful answers and comments.  This builds the community by awarding the active and knowledgeable users.

Comment: I would and I tried, but I am not allowed (reputation is not sufficient).